# Interfacing to SQLite

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, sqlite

I am attempting to interface with a SQLite.  In my project I have sqlite3.c and 6_1.cpp (my main source file).

When I attempt to compile, I receive many errors that are similar to this error: undefined reference to `dlerror'.  Based on what I've read this error indicates the gcc compiler isn't properly linked to certain libraries.  However, the errors I receive occur within sqlite3.c, not 6_1.cpp.  Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: With what libraries are you linking? And are you really compiling with `eclipse3.c`?

Comment: Good Catch.  I meant sqlite3.c.  I've corrected my Question.

Comment: When I attempt to link dlfcn.h to sqlite3.c to resolve the undefined reference, the compiler can not find dlfcn.h even though it is located in /usr/include.

Comment: `dlfcn.h` is not a library. Try `dl` or `libdl`.

Comment: the command I used to attempt to link was "gcc sqlite3.c -ldlfcn -lpthread"

Comment: That parameter would be `-ldl`.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your recommendation. I received the following response.  Do you have any insight into this?  ~/workspace/sql_test$ gcc sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: the errors related to dl and pthread within the sqlite3.c resource.  The only error associated with 6_1.cpp is Make:***[sql_test] Error 1.  Don't I have to link the libraries to the file with the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build your program, use the following commands:

```
gcc -c sqlite3.c
g++ -c 6_1.cpp
gcc -o 6_1 6_1.o sqlite3.o -ldl -lpthread
```

You should read up on [make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the recommended article.